# How to find integrable upper bound for a hyperbolic function?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

How do I find an upper bounds for the function

$$h(x)=\frac{1}{(\cosh(x)-1)^{1/3}}$$

on $(0,2]$? I have tried to use the monotone convergence theorem on intervals the functions $h(x)\chi_{[\epsilon,2]}$ but calculating the integral and it’s limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ is not viable.

Comment: Please feel free to accept and up vote an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\frac1{(\cosh(x)-1)^{1/3}}=\frac1{(2\sinh^2(x/2))^{1/3}}=O\left(\frac1{x^{2/3}}\right)$$

which is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,2]$